# Reload a function without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax, oop

I want to callout a function without the page is reloading. 
I know that this is possible with AJAX but i don't know how it works with calling a function.

I want to put a timer so it will reload the function every 3 seconds, so the users doesnt need to reload the page everytime to see if there is a new message.

```
$object = new Messages();
$object->ShowMessage($nick);
```

ShowMessage(); is the function that i want to call out every 3 seconds.

Full code :

```
public function ShowMessage() {

    $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bericht");
    $st->execute();
    if($st->rowCount() == 0){
        echo 'There is no message jet!';
    }  

        foreach ($st as $bericht){
        $uid = $bericht['uid'];

        $nick = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
        $nick->bindParam(1, $uid);
        $nick->execute();

            foreach($nick as $name) {   

            $image = $name['foto'];

        if($image == 'nophoto.jpg'){
        echo '<img src="image/nophoto.jpg" width="60px" height="30px">';

        } else {
        echo '<img src="image/'; echo $image.'"'; echo ' width="60px" height="30px">';
        }
        echo json_encode($name['name']) .': ';
        echo json_encode($bericht['message']).' <br> ';

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well i dont know if it would work,but you can reload a div through jquery,and inside that div you can put your php function.

Comment: You can do that with ajax and a simple handler. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926588/reload-a-function-without-reloading-the-page/23926685#23926685) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with ajax. In order to do that, you need to implement ajax client function on frontend and a handler for processing ajax request. In frontend you can use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) for [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) operations;

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get( "handler.php", function( data ) {
      // You can use data. It is in json format. 
      // Ex: alert(data.message) . "message" is one of the 
      // fields of returned array in php handler file
    }); 
}, 3000);
```

**handler.php**

```
<?php
    $object = new Messages();
    $result = $object->ShowMessage($nick); 
    // I assume this returns array. 
    // Ex: array("type" => "error", "message" => "Error occured on feed");
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**Update: If you do not want to use json data**

Update your code like below. Only use `echo`, you do not need to return json data.

```
public function ShowMessage() {

    $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bericht");
    $st->execute();
    if($st->rowCount() == 0){
        echo 'There is no message jet!';
    }  

        foreach ($st as $bericht){
        $uid = $bericht['uid'];

        $nick = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
        $nick->bindParam(1, $uid);
        $nick->execute();

            foreach($nick as $name) {   

            $image = $name['foto'];

        if($image == 'nophoto.jpg'){
        echo '<img src="image/nophoto.jpg" width="60px" height="30px">';

        } else {
        echo '<img src="image/'; echo $image.'"'; echo ' width="60px" height="30px">';
        }
        echo $name['name'] .': ';
        echo $bericht['message'].' <br> ';

    }

    }
}
```

and in js;

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get( "handler.php", function( data ) {
      // alert(data);
    }); 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: this echo `"NewOne": "New Message"` but is not showing when i `$.get` _handler.php_

Comment: @user3674846 Could you please put your code in your question ?

Comment: @user3674846 you are returning lots of things in your code. First, decide what data to return ( you can put data in an array as key=>value), or you can echo all content as normal html. Could you please construct an array and populate it with your data and put only one `echo json_encode($yourArr);`.

Comment: I need all data to return for images,nick and message, i don't know how to populate it, i'm new to this. alert(data.message) gives undefined http://testoop.hopto.org

Comment: @user3674846 Could you please see my updated answer? Update section

Comment: What do i need to do instead of alert(data): to show data in section alert(data); give now the array in it

Comment: @user3674846 in `showMessage` function, you won't use json_encode anymore. See my anser, just use echo

Comment: yes i did but what do i need to use in setInterval(function() {
    `$.get( "handler.php", function( data ) {
      // alert(data);
    }); 
}, 3000);` to show data

Comment: Remove `//` before alert function. You will see your data in popup

Comment: Yes but i want to echo the data in it i tried `return data;` but doenst show the data

Comment: In order to check ajax is working, open your web browser console and click Net tab (firefox) or Network tab(chrome). You will see ajax request there. Please click one of them and check response field. If you cannot see data there, there is something wrong in php side

Comment: I checked Network > handler.php > Response and the data is showing up in there but not in profile.php where i'm loading handling.php

Comment: It shows the same output but in popup when i use return data; it wont show in the page.

Comment: In order to show in page you can use `$("body").append(data)` instead of `alert(data)`

Comment: Yes this works, but everytime it refreshes it shows again the new message like this : NewOne: New Message 
NewOne: New Message 
NewOne: New Message 
NewOne: New Message

Comment: ok add an element like `<div id="message"></div>` in your html body and update js like this `$("#message").html(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that integrating javascript to your php code.
Using jquery, you can take a look at `$.post` function. You can rise the event with the javascript function `window.setInterval(yourFunction(),3000)`

You also need to create a php page that will reply to the Ajax request, that will be passed as a parameter to the `$.post`

Answer (score 0):

Just call that script via ajax:

```
.html:
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "showMessageScript.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {nick: $("#nick").val(), token: <?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>},
    success: function(jsonData){
        $('#display').text(jsonData['message']);
    }
  });
},
3000);
```

---

```
showMessageScript.php:

function showMessage($nick) {
   $object = new Messages();
   $object->ShowMessage($nick);
   echo json_encode(array('message': 'Your message is here'));
}

// check if authorized to do some action
if (!empty($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'] && !empty($_POST['nick'])) {
    showMessage($nick);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('message': 'not authorized'));
}
```